# MySQL Workbench Cannot Connect Server (2003)

Tags: mysql, database, service, database-connection, workbench

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAri0.png)I've exhausted every resource I've found online. I'm a neophyte with MySQL (postgres seems a lot easier to connect to server but schema design and CRUD appears easier in MySQL so I'd prefer to get this up and running). I'm running this on windows machine and have terminal, bash, mysql shell tools but that's about it.

I'm trying to connect MySQL locally to a server. I've gone through the process of uninstalling and reinstalling MySQL via the mysql-installer-web-community-8.X.exe and manually adding what was necessary.

When I initialize the app(MySQL workbench 8.0) and select my server instance there I see there is 'no connection established'. I've selected (from the side nav) 'Startup/Shutdown' and attempted to 'Start Server' but have been unsuccessful and received the dreaded "unable to connect to localhost (2003).

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. services >> mysql80 >> enabled/start running
2. edit variables >> environment variables >> path >> edit >> new >> 'enter path to serverX.X\bin
3. checking to see if the mysql my.cnf is in \serverX.X\bin

Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOb8O.png)

Please help as I am very close to losing what little hair I have left.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. services >> mysql80 >> enabled/start running
2. edit variables >> environment variables >> path >> edit >> new >> 'enter path to serverX.X\bin
3. checking to see if the mysql my.cnf is in \serverX.X\bin

I was expecting to get connected to server but still have 'no connection established' message and (2003) error

Comment: The problem is not the error message that you've highlighted, but the fact that MySQL won't start in the first place. Check the Windows Event Viewer and the mysql server log file to see why this is happening.

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)? Please edit your question to include the text